# Efficient way to port content from Tridion 2011 to Web 8.5

Tags: content-porter

I am in need to find out a solution to port content which are in **Tridion 2011 sp1** to **Web 8.5**. My initial plan is to use import export service along with content porter. I am trying to create the export package using 'content porter 2013' and feed the package to my .net application which will try to import it using import service. I have used "Mapping2013" class to map the publication and folders, but the mapping doesn't seem to work. Could anyone guide me how to achieve the same using import export service. The blueprint is not identical, we have made many a changes in blueprint structure.
I am trying to do what is mentioned in the below blog--
http://tridioninternals.blogspot.com/2014/01/import-package.html?view=flipcard

Comment: Could you elaborate on how exactly the mapping doesn't seem to work? Also include code where you create and apply mappings before importing content.

Comment: I have created a export package using 'content porter 2013 sp1' from Tridion 2011 sp1 and using my .net application I am porting the package(zip) into web 8.5. I am refering to the mention blog http://tridioninternals.blogspot.com/2014/02/manual-mappings-demystified-folder.html?view=flipcard for writing the .net application. Could you assist me in case have experience on content porting between lower version to higher version of SDL.